# IOmeter v/s FIO on Windows VM

Tags: windows, storage, benchmarking

I have a Windows VM which have disks on high performance storage. I have both **FIO**(http://bluestop.org/fio/) and **IOmeter**(http://www.iometer.org/) installed on it. I want to be able to saturate the disks to obtain max IOPs through FIO, but I see that FIO is not reaching the IOmeter IOPs level(FIO is showing around 100k IOPs lesser than IOmeter).

**IOmeter config:**

- 1 worker per disk (8 disks)
- 64 oio on each worker (iodepth)
- 4k random writes (workload)
- 4kb akigned IOs

**FIO config:**

```
[global]
rw=randread
rwmixread=100
blocksize=4096
blockalign=4096
ioengine=windowsaio
group_reporting=1
iodepth=64
description=fio 4KB random read 8disk
time_based=1
runtime=300
direct=1
numjobs=8   //Keeping it at 1 job per disk as in IOmeter gave even lower IOPs

[fio-job-01]
filename=\\.\PhysicalDrive1
[fio-job-02]
filename=\\.\PhysicalDrive2
[fio-job-03]
filename=\\.\PhysicalDrive3
[fio-job-04]
filename=\\.\PhysicalDrive4
[fio-job-05]
filename=\\.\PhysicalDrive5
[fio-job-06]
filename=\\.\PhysicalDrive6
[fio-job-07]
filename=\\.\PhysicalDrive7
[fio-job-08]
filename=\\.\PhysicalDrive8
```

Is there something that I can add in my FIO config to improve the IOPs?

Thanks.

Comment: NB: Your `blockalign` will make no difference (in this particular scenario) as you are asking for the same alignment as your `blocksize` and you aren't using a range of different block sizes via `bsrange`...

Comment: You say "1 worker per disk (8 disks)" but you will likely NOT have 1 worker per disk - you will have around 8 per disk.

Comment: Also, please include which version of fio you are using (you never know). Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen https://serverfault.com/a/754231 : "IOMeter does not avoid the cache for raw devices." ? Because you're using `direct=1` you've instructed `fio` to bypass the cache, giving it a disadvantage.